# Bootstrap: Div background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I am attempting to learn the basics. However, I have put a color background for the div and it is only appears when I have resize the browser. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="header">
         <div class="col-md-8"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
             <br />
             <br />
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <p>
                 <a href="#">HOME</a>
                 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                 <a href="#">SERVICES</a> 
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                 <a href="#">NEWS</a> 
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                 <a href="#">CAREERS</a> 
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                 <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
             </p>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



.container {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}           

#header{
    background-color:#e4e4e4;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also override the bootstrap css code by using,
!important property like.

```
#header{ background-color: #000 !important;}
```

Comment: You should never use !important if you could resolve the issue by using css specificity !

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code in code-pen and it works fine for me and applying background color even if i don't resize the browser.
And I found there are no opening tags for html, body and container in your code. Make sure it is not breaking! Happy coding!
http://codepen.io/lakshman_kotipalli/pen/qZBbVN?editors=1010

```
<html>

<head>
</head>
 <body>
<div id="header">
<div class="col-md-8">
  <img src="images/logo.png">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><br/><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <p>
    <a href="#">HOME</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#">SERVICES</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">NEWS</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">CAREERS</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">CONTACT</a></p>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use [bootstarp](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) media query

```
    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
        #header{
    background-color:red; }
    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
     #header{
    background-color:white; }
    }
    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    #header{
    background-color:green; }
    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    #header{
    background-color:blue; }
    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    #header{
    background-color:black;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion don't edit bootstarp file,
create a css file and add  **bootstarp media query**  in that file,

*don't forgot to include your css file before bootstrap*

example

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```